# Can't GET data protected by JWT despite a correctly issued token

Tags: javascript, angular, authorization, jwt

I have the following, working method for returning my objects.

```
getWorkers(): any {
  const url = ...
  return new Observable<any>(emitter => {
    this.http.get(url).subscribe(
      result => {
        result.json().map(...).forEach(...);
        emitter.complete();
      },
      error => error);
  });
}
```

Now, I made a change to the backend by protecting the endpoint by JWT. Of course, the original method fails now and I've added fetching the token from the REST API. It's being returned with the correct hashes. The problem is that I'm not sure how to jack it into the original response.

```
getWorkers(): any {
  const url = ...

  this.http.post(environment.sec, { credential: "1234" })
    .subscribe(secRes => console.warn(secRes.json()));

  return new Observable<any>(emitter => {
    let authorization = null;

    this.http.post(environment.secUrl, { credential: "1234" })
      .subscribe(
        secRes => {
          authorization = secRes.json();

          this.http.get(url, authorization).subscribe(
            result => {
              result.json().map(...).forEach(...);
              emitter.complete();
            },
            error => error);
        });
  });
}
```

I've tried sending in a few combinations of the result from the first call like *authorization* object in full as well as *authorization.token* field of it. Nothing produces a different result - it comes back unauthorized. In fact, I noticed that the program doesn't even execute the statements in result part!

What can I be doing wrong?

NB. I want to understand the mechanics of it so I want to resolve it without using any 3rd party packages including the generally recommended [angular2-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-jwt).

Answer (score 0):

The authorization token needs to be passed in the headers

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + Cookie.get('token'));
return this.httpClient.get(environment.api_url + 'orders', {
  headers: headers}
);
```

Comment: I've found the [HttpHeaders class](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders), which to my big surprise was in *@angular/common/http* for some reason (I expected it to me in *@angular/http* or at least *@angular/common*). However, I can't locate *Cookie* class in the docs for Angular API. Which version are you using?

Comment: Also, it seems that *get(...)* requires something of type *RequestOptionArgs*, which is incompatible with *HttpHeaders*. I'm too uncertain to suggest a change - what do you make of it?

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Ignore the specifics of the code, they're meant to illustrate the use of HttpHeaders. The code above is using HttpClient not Http since Http is deprecated in v5. You can use HttpClient, just substitute the Http module in your constructor with HttpClient but keep in mind you might have to edit some of your code that uses Http in that component.

Comment: I see I was a bit out of date on the most recent classes for HTTP communication. now that I've read up on them, I get the first half to work, I can see the following header in my call: *Authorization:bla.bli.blu* (I skipped the *Bearer* and *Cookie.get* parts for simplicity). However, the server still gives me 401 but perhaps it's an issue with the configuration on the backend?